# How do I iterate over CIDR blocks in JQ?

Tags: json, parsing, jq

Basically I'm trying to iterate through my AWS security groups to find any CIDR's using 0.0.0.0/0.

Here is my example JSON file:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [],
            "Description": "AWS OpsWorks load balancer - do not change or delete",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 80,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 443,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 443,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "AWS-OpsWorks-LB-Server",
            "OwnerId": "056146032236",
            "GroupId": "sg-7dd13739"
        },
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ],
            "Description": "SG for bastion hosts",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "bastion-host-sg",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 80,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 1991,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 1991,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 8080,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 8080,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 1194,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 1194,
                    "IpProtocol": "udp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 30,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": -1,
                    "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 1194,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 1194,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 53,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 53,
                    "IpProtocol": "udp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 53,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 53,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 443,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 443,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 8,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": -1,
                    "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "bastion-host-sg",
            "VpcId": "vpc-effd0e8a",
            "OwnerId": "056146032236",
            "GroupId": "sg-0f60196a"
        }
      ]
}
```

Here is the command I'm trying to run, but get an error:

```
$ cat sg-small.json | jq '.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[].IpRanges[] | map(select(any(.CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0")))'    
jq: error (at <stdin>:227): Cannot iterate over string ("0.0.0.0/0")
```

Any thoughts as to why this is happening.  That method seems to work for other things that aren't IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression:

```
.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[].IpRanges[]
```

is just a stream of CidrIp objects, so that's not what you want.

The following will select the SecurityGroups that meet the criterion:

```
.SecurityGroups[]
| select(any( .IpPermissions[].IpRanges[]; .CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0"))
```

Whether this is precisely what you want is unclear since you haven't specified that. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing the error

```
Cannot iterate over string ("0.0.0.0/0")
```

is because with your data the first portion of your filter

```
.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[].IpRanges[]
```

generates a sequence of objects

```
{
  "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
}
...
```

The `map` portion of your filter iterates over the values in each of these objects, passing

```
"0.0.0.0/0"
```

to the expression `select(any(.CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0"))` where `any` tries to iterate over all the values within the string and fails with the error you observe.

If you only want to see a sequence of `{"CidrIp":...}` objects as above you can eliminate the `map` and `any`:

```
  .SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[].IpRanges[] 
| select(.CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0")
```

If you would rather collect those objects into an array you could remove the `any` and move some of the iteration into the `map` e.g.

```
  .SecurityGroups 
| map(.IpPermissions[].IpRanges[] | select(.CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0"))
```

producing

```
[
  {
    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
  },
  ....
```

The explict construction of the result array is easier to see if you replace `map` with its definition.  Since `map(f)` is defined as `[ .[] | f ]` the above filter is the same as this one:

```
  .SecurityGroups 
| [ .[] | .IpPermissions[].IpRanges[] | select(.CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0") ]
```